# Where is App.config?

Tags: vb.net, enterprise-library

I'm trying to set up logging with Microsoft's Enterprise Library (log4net seems to be a dead project). I'm using VB .NET 2008 and VS 2008. I've searched all over the MSDN documentation, CodePlex docs (including the Hands-On labs that installed and then vanished), and online tutorials to no avail.

They all refer to a mysterious "configuration file" or "App.config" that I can't find and can't seem to add. I even tried adding a new text file and renaming it "App.config" but that only made VS 2008 spit out a red wavy line on a blank file.

Any suggestions for finding the elusive app.config would be greatly appreciated.

(and, if that makes the EntLib configuration tool show up, I'll be absolutely delighted)

Edit:
I've been tricked!

The tree in VS 2008 isn't a true superset-subset relationship, which is why I got so frustrated.

To wit, the top of the tree:
[alt text http://static.zooomr.com/images/7954203_910064e809.jpg](http://static.zooomr.com/images/7954203_910064e809.jpg)

And a 'sub-section' of the tree.
[alt text http://static.zooomr.com/images/7954204_69e03c8502.jpg](http://static.zooomr.com/images/7954204_69e03c8502.jpg)

Comment: `log4net` isn't dead, it's just stable.  There's been several bugfix commits in the past 2 months, at least: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Im pretty sure you can use web.config if youre in a web app or web solution.

Otherwise, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(VS.80).aspx)

[EDIT] In my VS the app file can be added like:
Add new item -> General -> Application Configuration file

Answer (score 3):

Should be in the same directory as binaries, but you have to add it to your solution first, using Visual Studio window for adding new files to soultion.

```
Add -> New Item -> Application configuration file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an app config file to any vb project by

> right clicking on the project -> Add-> New Item -> ...

and selecting either

> Application Configuration File

or selecting

> Web Configuration File

(for app.config or web.config respectively)

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add my $0.02 as I stumbled on this question with frustrated googling, and my situation wasn't as others have described here.  I created a new winforms project, didn't see app.config, and went to add it as others have described.  Wasn't in the list.  I turned on "Show all files" in Solution Explorer, and it was already there, but not a part of the project.  Right clicked on it and selected "Include in project," and now I'm good to go.  No idea why it created the file, but didn't include it in the project.  (This is VS2010, btw.)